# no subscription found in windows azure account

Tags: azure

I'm very new to azure and learning now. My company gave me an account on azure (email and password) I want to deploy my project.when I sign in with my credentials and go to portals, it says no subscription found that I should sign out and sign in with another account.though my account is correct.what is going on? how do I get a subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Empty cache and hard reload or try to run in incognito mode.