# This account has no subscription - Publishing to Azure from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

Earlier this year I successfully deployed a MVC app to Azure from Visual Studio.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing again, but now I am told my azure account "has no subscription".

[image]

However I am 100% positive I do have a subscription associated with my email. My old MVC app still runs and I can see my Pay-as-you-go is properly charged.

[image]

### What I Have tried to fix it

- Emptied my browser caches, history, cookies etc.
- Removed my account from Visual Studio, restarted, and added them again.
- Formatted my computer and reinstalled everything (not really because of this problem, but the timing was perfect).
- Updated the Azure SDK to the newest 2.9.5.

I did the following things above based on advice from these pages:

[Visual Studio not finding my Azure subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507589/visual-studio-not-finding-my-azure-subscriptions)

[Unable to publish to Azure with VS2015](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/294be186-487b-417b-9ed0-850f9d931778/unable-to-publish-to-azure-with-vs2015?forum=lightswitch)

[No subscription found in windows azure account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795886/no-subscription-found-in-windows-azure-account)

But alas, no luck.

The only thing that comes to thought is I tried to add an Azure Pass to my account, but without luck. But I can't see how that should change anything...

So my question is: How do I make Visual Studio recognize my current Pay-as-you-go subscription, so I can publish my services, apps, etc. from Visual Studio directly?

Or at least: What has gone wrong? Whom can I contact to get help with this?

As always, thank you for your time and patience, and please write a comment if you need further information.

Comment: Have you tried to use server explorer first? I always connect via server explorer.

Comment: I opened the Server Explorer tab, right clicked the Azure option and clicked "Connect to Microsoft Azure Subscription". I was then told my subscription was not supported by server explorer. BUT! When I try to publish now, Visual Studio can see both my Pay-as-you-go subscription AND my Azure Pass. E.g. you saved the day @apr. Please write your solution as an answer and I will accept it. Otherwise I'll write my own in a week or so :)

Comment: I have also a pay as you go subscription, but my subscription started as an msdn azure subscription. It is strange that your subscription listed as non supported. Corrupted azure sdk installation(?)

Comment: Might be, but now I can publish so I'm happy :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try to connect first via the server explorer (ctrl+alt+s). (The server explorer has an azure root node, if the azure sdk installed)

If you have connected, the publish wizard won't ask (usually) for sign in again.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the solution was as follows:

Open Server Explorer in Visual Studio, right-click on Azure and select "Manage and filter subscriptions":

[Screenshot of Manage Subscriptions Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laukW.png)

Click the Certificates tab, click Import, then click Download subscription file. This will take you to the azure portal page where you can download a .publishsettings file for your subscription. After downloading that file, click the Browse button in the Import dialog shown above and select that file.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. To solve it I opened the server explorer (ctrl+alt+s) and refreshed the Azure connection. It still said 0 subscriptions, but in the publishing options I could connect without any issue.

[image]

Comment: What if my account is not eligible for subscription and cannot be upgraded as Pay-as-You-GO ?